# Form object property not getting update in Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

**User Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends Model 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public int age;     
}
```

In my controller, trying to update the user submitted form

```
Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Updating one of the property of form object, using following snippet.

```
userForm.data().put("name","updated_name");     // Trying to update name field.
```

Verifying, whether the change is reflected or not. Actually it's getting updated by verifying its log.

```
Logger.info("submitted form :: "+userForm.toString());  // Form(of=class models.User, data={name=updated_name, age=25}, value=Some(models.User@768d00), errors={})

User user = userForm.get();

// But here it returning only the original value.
Logger.info("name :: "+user.name);  // Getting Old name.
```

For updating the name property in my controller i can directly update like following

`user.name = "updated_name"`, but i just want to know why the above approach not working?

Comment: It depends on play framework to bind data to object. You have a Map that is updated, what doesn't mean the entity object itself is. That map is probably 'converted' right after the request is done. It could be updated as well, but it wasn't implemented that way, as you have found

Comment: You should update the name in the User object i.e. after `User user = userForm.get();`

Comment: @nbz  Thanks for reply, i know it already, but i am looking for different approach. Which i already mentioned in my post.